# Created new branch in remote repo, now can't checkout new branch locally

Tags: branch, tortoisegit, git-checkout

I just pushed some code to a new branch in my remote repo `feature\add-user`. In my local repo I am currently on an older branch, which `feature\add-user` builds on to. I am using TortoiseGit, but when attempting to checkout the new feature branch, `feature\add-user` does not show up and there is no option to type the name of a branch. The branch is visible in the remote repo itself.

I've tried pulling the latest version of the branch I'm currently on thinking this may "refresh" TortoiseGit's view of the remote repo, but to no avail. Aside from cloning a new copy of the remote repo at `feature\add-user` is there a way to find this new feature branch using TortoiseGit?

Comment: In order to refresh the remote view, use Fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the switch/checkout dialog your could selected the origin branch, and that will make a new local branch.

For example with the branch "dev" which is only at origin and not local:

[image]

if you can't select the origin branch, you could fetch it after pushing the "..."-button:

[image]